# combobox having combobox item and sub item

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm new in wpf, want to develop app in c#, where combobox will have 3 subitem(i.e audi, bmw and custom) selecting custom will again show the combobox will have 2 radio buttons, and one combobox in it.

So combobox will have item and some item again will have subitem. This is similar to menu and some menu item has again submenu, e.g CAR combobox will have 3 combo item i.e. audi,bmw and customise car. Selecting customize car will show popup, having 2radio btn and one combobox. so user can select either audi, bmw or customize car option

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. And No you probably [don't need to create a custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx#when_to_write_a_new_control) for this.

Comment: @user3106005 - Don't forget to mark this as answered (checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the options of the main `ComboBox` are in some way hard-coded. Whether that's in xaml or in code. Either way I would define a method for the `SelectionChanged` event on the combo box and open a new window, when `Custom` is selected.

```
<ComboBox Name="..." ..., SelectionChanged="carType_SelectionChanged" />
```

Defining this here in the xaml will automatically generate the `carType_SelectionChanged` method in the code for this window. If it doesn't it will look something like this:

```
carType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

This popup window can be another wpf window that is called by the main. This can contain two radio buttons and a `ComboBox` populated in the same way that the main window's combobox is. My understanding of what you want from this popup window is that the `ComboBox` displays the same information. However for this I wouldn't have the check on the custom option to open a popup, as this has already occurred at this point.

If you need help calling the new window inside the `SelectionChanged` method, let me know and I can point you in the right direction for doing that.